# Best practice: how to implement many-to-many relations using Domain Models without framework

Tags: php, database, domain-driven-design

Hello stackoverflow members,

I'm using pure PHP to implement a Domain Model. I have two entities, entity `dog` and entity `human` which acts as the owner of the dog.

This is a many-to-many relationship. A `owner` can have more than one `dog` and a `dog` is owned by many `humans` (let's say the dog belongs to a family or a couple).

I have a database table for `dog` and `human` and also the n:n connection table. I have the two entities which are POPOs. And I also have two repositories, one for `dog` and one for `human`. These repositories have the crud operations and are responible for the database queries.

Which repository is responsible for managing the n:n table?

## Example:

entity `dog` has a property array with all connected `human`'s and vice versa. If i create a new `human` like: `$human = new Human('name');` and let him own an already existing `dog` like: `$human->addDog($dog);` Who is responsible for the n:n connection?
I can do `$dogRepo->Update($human->getDogs()[0]);` to update the dog in DB or I can do `$humanRepo->Insert($human)`. Should the DogRepo also insert the new `human` (utilizing the HumanRepo)? Should the HumanRepo also update the `dog` (utilizing the DogRepo). Or is the business logic responsible for this? (call `insertHuman()` and `updateDog()` seperately from the business logic).
On all of this approaches I don't know which repository is responible for the n:n table?

Sound like a common question but i couldn't find a suitable solution on the web.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In DDD we design our Aggregates based on the business rules. Each Aggregate protects its own invariants. There are no tables or relation tables in our head when we design them, just invariants and consistency requirements.

That being said, you are having difficulties because you haven't identified the invariants or there are none.

Does the human that own a dog behave in some particular way? Are some human commands rejected if the Human doesn't/does own a Dog ? Then you add to the `Human` Aggregate a list of owned dog ID's (and not dog instances!).

Does the dog that is owned by a human behave differently from a dog that has no master? Then add to the `Dog` Aggregate a list of owner IDs.

Or is this *relation* between them shown only in the UI? Then add it as a separate Aggregate, i.e. `DogOwnershipByAHuman(id, dogId, humanId)` to not pollute the `Dog` or `Human` Aggregates with data that they don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Both repositories should only change their corresponding tables, since this is their main functionality (following the `Single responsibility principle`). These repositories would be wrapped by a `Service` (a wrapper class which has utility functions for managing relations), where the service would be responsible for altering both databases correctly. So this service could have a function like `assignDogToHuman($humanId, $dogId)`, where this function would call both repositories and change their data accordingly.

By doing this you make sure that the repositories have one responsibility (updating their own table) and the service has the responsibility of managing the relations between `dogs` and `humans`.

This also provides you with the added benefit that the repository layer is now replaceable. I.e. if you ever decide to change the database (for example from Mysql to MongoDB), only the repositories have to be swapped/updated since the implementation of the functions called by `assignDogToHuman` should stay the same and for this service it does not matter what the underlying database is.

I hope this helps you, if you have any questions feel free to ask